# is it good practice to mark runAllTests = false in salesforce

Tags: managed-package

I am creating managed package & don't want the test classes to be run in subscriber/destination org when the package is installed.
This can be achieved by setting the field runAllTests = false
But is it good practice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For managed packages, the package upload process runs the tests that are included in the managed package and will only allow the process to complete if all the tests pass and the coverage requirements are met. That is not something you have any control over.

When managed packages are installed or upgraded, tests are not run. (If they were they would very likely fail because of e.g. local validation rules and other logic that interfere with the managed package tests.)

During the development process, I strongly suggest that you do run tests as much as possible so that breaking changes are identified immediately and can be dealt with at the time a change is made; it is much easier to identify the cause of a problem that way. So when using the [Ant deploy task](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_deploying_ant.htm), keep `runalltests=true`.